# list tree structure toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-structures

I have a tree structure of nested lists. I am trying to hide the nested lists until the user clicks on them so I then call toggle(). 
Here is my code:

```
var $list = $('#subject-list');
        var data = [
            { name: "A" },
            { name: "B" },
            { name: "C" },
            {
                name: "G",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "D",
                        children: [
                            { name: "1" },
                            { name: "2" },
                            { name: "3" }
                        ]
                    },
                    { name: "E" },
                    { name: "F" }                    
                ]
            }
        ];

        var populateSubjectTree = function (data, list) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                
                if (typeof (data[i].children) !== "undefined") {
                    var listItem = $('<li class="no-style"><input class="checkbox-he" type="checkbox"><label class="label-pointer">&nbsp;' + data[i].name + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span></label><ul class="has-children collapse"></ul></li>');
                    list.append(listItem);
                    var childList = listItem.find('ul');
                    populateSubjectTree(data[i].children, childList);
                } else {
                    var listItem = $('<li class="no-style"><input class="checkbox-he" type="checkbox"><label>&nbsp;' + data[i].name + '</label></li>');
                    list.append(listItem);
                }
            }

            list.find('label').click(function () {
                if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
                    console.log($(this).siblings('ul'));
                    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
                }
            })
        };
```

It seems to work fine for top-level list items in the tree but not for lower level ones, here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kuv4tkqv/

At the moment if I click on item G it's fine but not in the nested element - D. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: So you want to toggle the element G as well as its children on clicking?

Comment: well on clicking G it should toggle its direct children only. and then when clicking D it should toggle its direct children as well. so they're independent of each other in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below funcition, i.e $('.label-pointer') instead of  list.find('label')

```
         $('.label-pointer').click(function () {
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
                console.log($(this).siblings('ul'));
                $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
            }
          })
```

instead of

```
        list.find('label').click(function () {
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
                console.log($(this).siblings('ul'));
                $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
            }
        })
```

Comment: hmmm, it works but I don't understand why. when I'm targeting the labels, I'm already checking if they have any nested lists before calling toggle(). Could you explain what is happening here please?

Comment: It seems the problem is happening when I change $('.label-pointer') to list.find('.label-pointer')

Comment: If list.find('label') returns more than one object(in your case 2) you will have to loop through them and bind click event for all of them with the toggle functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add e.preventdefault();

```
list.find('label').click(function () {
                if ($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0) {
                    console.log($(this).siblings('ul'));
                    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
                        e.preventdefault();
                }
            })
```